# How to parse the same key name as string and object for JSON parsing?

Tags: android, json

Hi in the below response value is string and same value acts as a object .How to parse the json like this of situation in android

Can any one please help me how to resolve it .

For example value in pojo class i was defined as a string but after that loop was failing because in the next value is a object.

How to run two at a time string and objects with same key name

Response:

```
"fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "subject",
                                "value": "Meeting with Lead",
                                "label": "Subject",
                                "uitype": "2"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "reminder_time",
                                "value": "0",
                                "label": "Send Reminder",
                                "uitype": "30"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "assigned_user_id",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "19x1",
                                    "label": "Administrator"
                                },
                                "label": "Assigned To",
                                "uitype": "53",
                                "type": {
                                    "defaultValue": {
                                        "value": "19x1",
                                        "label": "Administrator"
                                    }
                                }
                            },]
```

Loop for Fields

private void fetchJSON(){

```
sessionId = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("sessionId");
String operation = "syncModuleRecords";
String module = "Accounts";
String syncToken="";
String mode="public";
final GetNoticeDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetNoticeDataService.class);

/** Call the method with parameter in the interface to get the notice data*/
Call<SyncModule> call = service.GetSyncModuleList(operation, sessionId, module,syncToken,mode);

/**Log the URL called*/
Log.i("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");

call.enqueue(new Callback<SyncModule>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SyncModule> call, Response<SyncModule> response) {

        Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

            SyncModule syncModule = response.body();


            String success = syncModule.getSuccess();

            if (success.equals("true")) {
                SyncResults results = syncModule.getResult();

                Sync sync=results.getSync();

                ArrayList<SyncUpdated> syncUpdateds=sync.getUpdated();

                for(SyncUpdated syncUpdated:syncUpdateds){

                    ArrayList<SyncBlocks> syncBlocks=syncUpdated.getBlocks();

                    for(SyncBlocks syncBlocks1:syncBlocks){

                        String label=syncBlocks1.getLabel();

                        ArrayList<SynFields> synFields=syncBlocks1.getFields();

                        ArrayList<SynFields> jsonArray=syncBlocks1.getFields();


                        for(SynFields synFields1:synFields){
                            String name=synFields1.getName();
                            String value=synFields1.getValue();
                            String labelfield=synFields1.getLabel();

                            account_name.add(value);


                        }
                        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(),account_name);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

                    }


                }
```

Pojo class:

```
public class SynFields {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @SerializedName("label")
    @Expose
    private String label;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(SynFields synFields1:synFields){
     String name=synFields1.getName();
     //String value=synFields1.getValue();
     String labelfield=synFields1.getLabel();

      Object values = synFields1.getValue();

      if (values instanceof JSONObject) {
         //here, you get jsonObject
          JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(synFields1.getValue());

           // other stuff of   jsonObject1

      }else if (values instanceof String) {
           //here, you get string
           String your_string = synFields1.getValue();
      }

      account_name.add(value);
   }
```

Now in you pojo class
Replace

```
@SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private String value;
```

With

```
@SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private Object value;
```

Also you need change getter-settter method “value”to Object

hope this work :)

Comment: try to add inside of the for loop it is showing error for keys

Comment: @jyothi check edited answer. paste it in onResponse

Comment: @jyothi check edited answer, let me know if you not get it or if have any error

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(synFields1.getValue()); at this line?

Answer (score 0):

you can simple parse json to pojo or kotlin class by this

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

and you can easily get value if key is present.